# Effect of down mixing on complex demodulation method

Tags: demodulation, decimation

As I know, IQ demodulation (complex demodulation) consists of three steps:

1. Down mixing

   X(complex demodulation)(t)=X(real signal)(t).{exp⁡[(-i2π(f_demodulation).t)]}
2. low pass filtering
3. decimation

would you please explain what consequence would effect the demodulation procedure by implementing down mixing conversion in step1?

As a second question, when do we use complex demodulation instead of regular methods for demodulating the signal to extract specific frequencies?

Regards

Mahsa

Comment: Your question is unclear. I suggest writing down the equations for the three steps, and for the change you propose.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my question adding more details.